# Why logging is not working when I use pytest

Tags: python, pytest

When I run pytest, I am not seeing any log messages, how can I fix it, I tried to search for pytest.ini file which is not present in my local, I am new to pytest and need some help.

```
import test_todo_lib

import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.CRITICAL)
# NOTE: Run pytest using --capture=tee-sys option inorder to display standard output


def test_basic_unit_tests(browser):
    test_page = test_todo_lib.ToDoAppPage(browser)
    test_page.load()
    logging.info("Check the basic functions")
```

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html#live-logs

Comment: You defined logging level of `Critical` you won't see `Info` messeges. Also add `logger = logging.getLogger()` and call its info function `logger.info(...)`